# To what extent are 'asynchronous functions' asynchronous in ECMAScript-2017?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, async-await

ECMAScript-2017, just finalized about a month ago, introduces ['asynchronous functions'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function) as a new feature. To find out how 'asynchronous' they are, I carried out a test in Chrome:

```
async function af1(){
   for (let i=0; i<300; i++)
      await (new Promise(
                (resolve,reject)=>{
                   for (let j=0; j<=4; j++) console.log(j);resolve();}))
            .then(()=>{for (let j=100; j<=400; j+=100) console.log(j);});;
}

async function af2(){
   for (let i=0; i<300; i++)
      await (new Promise(
                (resolve,reject)=>{
                   for (let j=5; j<=9; j++) console.log(j);resolve();}))
            .then(()=>{for (let j=500; j<=900; j+=100)  console.log(j);});
}
af1();
console.log(300);
af2();
console.log(400);
// 0 1 2 3 4 300 5 6 7 8 9 400 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
// ......
```

Actually I was expecting a more randomized sequence.

Now, can I safely say that each block of code representing a promise or one of its then() callbacks is atomic, in the sense that execution of the code within the block is not interruptible by another part of the code within the same program?

Comment: "Asynchronous" does not have anything to do with "multithreading" or "parallelism". It's always one thread, and all synchronous code blocks execute exclusively until they complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing asynchronous code does not imply that the output will be random. When promises are resolved immediately (instead of being dependent on some uncontrolled external event), then the sequence of events is in fact predictable:

Everything that executes in the Promise constructor callback function will be executed at the time the promise is created, i.e. it runs synchronously before continuing with the code that follows `new Promise()`.

Then the rest of the synchronous code executes until the call stack is empty.

Then, as part of microtasks appended to the current task, the asynchronous `then` callbacks are executed, in the order the `then` methods were previously executed.

The `await` keywords will also influence the order of execution: the `async` function in which they occur will "stop", letting the calling code continue synchronously as if the `async` function had executed a `return` (it returns a promise). Once the promise provided to `await` is resolved, the `async` function will get its state restored asynchronously (after the current executing code ran until the call stack is empty), and continue as part of a microtask. The timing for this is the same as for a `then` callback.

This explains your output. There is no randomness involved.

#### Example

> Say, at the end of the first line of output, 900, what signals the execution to go back to `af1()`?

At the time 900 is output, there are two microtasks pending in the queue:

1) The `then` callback in `af1` has finished execution, returning a value of `undefined` (as it has no `return`), and this represents the promised value that `await` is waiting for. This is pending for asynchronous treatment while the current code is still running until the call stack is empty.

2) The `then` callback in `af2` has also finished execution: same principle.

As (1) is first in the microtask queue, this is what happens after 900 has been output and there is no more synchronous code to execute (the call stack is empty):

The JavaScript engine reads the microtask queue and takes the microtask to treat the first `await`: the function state is restored, including the state of its loop, and the loop continues. This means the promise constructor callback is executed synchronously, producing the first values you have in the second line of your output. ...etc.

Comment: What is confusing me is 'await'. Specifically, how does it know when to resume execution?

Comment: @ChongLipPhang when the promise on which is being "awaited" resolves or rejects.

Comment: I have added a paragraph about that.

Comment: Let me be clearer. Say, at the end of the first line of output, 900, what signals the execution to go back to af1()?

Comment: Never mind. I think I can understand it now. Basically the order is maintained in the stack. So I guess the answer to my question in the post is yes -- those blocks are atomic.

Comment: I added a paragraph about that. The order is maintained in a microtask queue (not stack, it is FIFO), which is consumed as part of the task.